# How to see that this equilibrium is a center?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Consider the system
$$
\dot{x}=y,\quad \dot{y}=-x+y^2.
$$

Obviously, $(0,0)$ is an equilibrium. The linearisation matrix at zero has purely imaginary eigenvalues. So, at least we know that zero is no hyperbolic equilibrium.

In fact, it is a center.

Whats the exact condition to have a center equilibrium? One conditions seems to be that we have only pure imaginary eigenvalues.

Comment: If the eigenvalues are complex with zero real parts (i.e. purely imaginary) then the fixed point is a center.

Comment: That is +i and -i?

Comment: Or any (real) multiple.

Comment: @Daniel How about say $x'=y+x^3$, $y'=−x+y^3$? Hint: $xx'+yy'=x^4+y^4$.

Comment: You should check Artem 's answer in the more general question of @Did http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1333918/periodic-orbits-of-even-perturbations-of-the-differential-system-x-y-y/1377123#1377123  You can also check Evgeny 's answer on my question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1577274/formal-proof-of-lyapunov-stability for another approach.

Comment: @CTNT Wow :) Funny fact is that this system is reversible too, with the same symmetry $(x(t), y(t)) \mapsto (x(-t), -y(-t))$.

Comment: So center means a pair of purely imaginary eigenvalues and reversible?

Comment: Do you want a quite general answer or do you want to study this particular system?

Comment: Rather this particular one

Comment: In this case it's better to stick to reversibility of this system. In general if you have $C^{\infty}$ (infinitely differentiable) system, having all zero Lyapunov values (that are mentioned in Artem's answer) is necessary and sufficient condition for having center equilibrium (as far as I remember). However, if your system is conservative or has symmetries, you can use this to conclude that equilibrium with purely imaginary eigenvalues is a center without computing all Lyapunov values.

Comment: @Evgeny Indeed, reversibility seems to be present in all systems in the form of a simple oscillator perturbed by even powers of the respective state as in Did's example.

Comment: @CTNT Well, Artem showed that it's not always true that such system posess center equilibrium at the origin. However, if we correct Did's hypothesis a bit (require $f(x)$ to be _odd_ instead of even), then the reversibility also applies.

Comment: @Evgeny I was referring to the system $$\ddot{x}+\omega^2 x+g_1(x)+g_2(\dot{x})=0$$ Correct me if I am wrong but if $g_2(\dot{x})$ is even ( $g_2(-\dot{x}) =g_2(\dot{x})$) and for arbitrary $g_1$ the reversibility seems to hold. If $(x(t),y(t))$ is a trajectory then $(x(-t),-y(-t))$ also is.

Comment: @CTNT You are absolutely correct, this system is reversible too. I think that I've misunderstood you, I thought about system from this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1333918/periodic-orbits-of-even-perturbations-of-the-differential-system-x-y-y

Answer (score 1):

This is not a direct answer to the question, but a description of the real trajectories.
[image]

[image]

The limit case $c=-\frac{1}{2}$ is the point $(x=0\:,\:y=0)$ which is an isolated point. Losely, one can say that a trajectory reduced to an isolated point is at equilibrium.

If we displace slightly $(x,y)$ from $(0,0)$ to any position close to $(0,0)$ but not exactly on $(0,0)$ it comes on an almost circular trajectory and so, doesn't come back to the center. In this sense, the equilibrium point $(0,0)$ can be said "unstable".

Around $(0,0)$ (with $-\frac{1}{2}<c\ll 0$ ) the equation of trajectories is approximately :
$$y^2=(c+\frac{1}{2}) +(2c+1)x+(2c)x^2+O(x^3)$$
$$\left( \sqrt{-2c} \:x+x_0\right)^2+y^2=r^2+O(x^3)$$
where $x_0=\frac{c+\frac{1}{2}}{\sqrt{-2c} }$ and $r=\sqrt{ \frac{2c-1}{4c} (c+\frac{1}{2}) }$

The trajectory  is an ellipse with center $(x_0\:,\:0)$ , with semiminor axis=$r$ and semimajor axis=$\frac{r}{\sqrt{-2c} }$.

The more $c$ is close to $-\frac{1}{2}$ , the more the trajectory is close to circular, with center close to $(0,0)$ and radius $r\simeq 0$ .

Comment: Don't call center equilibrium "unstable" :) it is Lyapunov stable, but not asymptotically Lyapunov stable

Comment: @Evgeny : Right, this is much more precise than loosely "unstable" in quotation marks. Thank you for the clarification.