# The zero point $(0,0)$ of $x'=x+y,y'=xy-bx-y$ is stable when $b>1$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Proof when $b>1$, the zero point $(0,0)$ of ODE $\left\{\begin{align}&x'=x+y\\&y'=xy-bx-y\end{align}\right.$ is stable.

I couldn't find a proper Lyapunov V function.

Let $v=x'$ we has 1st order ODE $v\frac{dv}{dx}=xv-x^2-bx$, but it has no suitable expressions

Comment: Did you find the critical points, the Jacobian, and then analyze the Jacobian at each critical point for the parameter b?

Comment: @Moo It has zero real part and non-zero imag part.

Comment: [Related](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1333918/6179) (see @Artem's detailed solution), here the perturbation term is $xy$.